# Is Infolog an alias to the class Info in Dynamics AX?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I am trying to understand how *Infolog* works within Dynamics AX. I understand that the following code will display the text in the infolog window.

> info("Hello World!");

I am aware that **info** is a static method on the **Global** class and therefore the method can be called by simply calling the name without actually specifying *`Global::`*

While looking into the method *info* in class *Global*, I noticed that it invokes `infolog.add`. Right-clicking on `add` and selecting the option `Lookup Definition` takes me to the method **add** in the class **Info**.

If the class in which the method *add* exists is named as *Info*, how is it being called from within `Global::info()` with the name **Infolog**?

The only logical conclusion that I can arrive at is that *Infolog* is an alias for the class *Info*. If that is correct, where is this alias defined in the AOT (*Application Object Tree*)?

I searched the AOT but found multiple references to the term *Infolog* but I couldn't find anything that would directly relate to an *Application* or *System* class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response to the same question I posted on Microsoft Dynamics communities forum helped me to understand the code better.

[Is Infolog an alias to the class Info? - Response on Microsoft Dynamics Community forum](https://community.dynamics.com/product/ax/f/33/t/93579.aspx)

Below shown code is from the static method `Global::info()`. I failed to notice that call to method **`add`** using the object **`infolog`** is actually an instance method and not static.

```
client server static Exception info(
    SysInfoLogStr txt, 
    URL helpUrl = '', 
    SysInfoAction _sysInfoAction = null)
{
    return infolog.add(Exception::Info, 
        getPrefix()+txt, 
        helpUrl, 
        _sysInfoAction, false);
}
```

In other words, `infolog` is an instance of class `Info`. After looking into the class *Info*, I found the `startup` method. I kept a breakpoint to debug the code and found that this method is called whenever the AX client is opened. This method in turn calls another method named `initBrowser`. Within the *initBrowser*, the following code seems to initialize the global instance of Infolog using a windows handle.

```
this.initializeInfolog(this.browser().hWnd());
```

The above menthod `initializeInfolog` exists in the System class `xInfo`, which is the parent class of Info. Since I cannot look into the class *xInfo*, I assume that this is where the instance of class `Info` with the name **`infolog`** is being created.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's an alias.  I think it's a global variable defined in the kernel level.

Edit: You answered your question while I was answer it...